# How can I skip data/labels in a period of time in Chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

Can you show me how I can skip data in a period of time in Chartjs?
e.g I have data from 10->11h30 am and 1h -> 2h pm. I built the chart in time type but I want to skip/remove the line from 11h30->1h or 2hpm -> 10h.

```
options = {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Time Point Data'
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            display: true,
            stacked: true,
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Date'
            },
            ticks: {
                major: {
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    fontColor: '#FF0000'
                },
            },
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            display: true,
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'value'
            },
        }]
    },
};
```

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH6op.png)
[Expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV97n.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Chart.JS will show whatever `labels` and `data` contain. Therefore you can create a function to remove a certain range.

Here is a sample with a line chart: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/xxRGVPW?editors=0010

The function `rangeWithSkips` will basically `filter` the input array between `startSkip` and `endSkip`. Later in the code you select the new range with:

```js
data: {
  labels: rangeWithSkips(3, 10).labels, // Pick the starting and end range here
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Volume",
      data: rangeWithSkips(3, 10).data // Pick the starting and end range here too
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is an updated version with that does exactly the same with a 2 inputs: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/yLVNOGX?editors=1011

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @adelriosantiago. You are a superstar.